# How to visualize the statement 'regular languages are closed under x,y... '?

Tags: regex, regular-language

I am studying DFA/ regular expression, I keep on encountering the statement

> regular languages are closed under union, intersection, complement etc.

I understand the definition of closure, which means that when we apply some operation on some element of the set, the resulting element should also be in the set.

However, none of the resources I referred to have any concrete examples of that? The prove it by equation, Could somebody help me visualize the statement above with an example of regex?

Comment: Instead of trying to visualise it with a regex, have you tried visualising it with a DFA yet?

Comment: @hvd aren't they both equivalent? and won't it be easier to do it with regex.

Comment: That's specifically why I would suggest it: you can express the exact same languages with DFAs and with regexes, so they are equivalent, but depending on what you want to do, NFAs or DFAs can be far more understandable than regexes, and in this case DFAs definitely are.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that in order to *find* the intersect of two regular expressions, it's virtually necessary that you convert them to automatons first. Thus, proving that regular expressions are closed under intersection pretty much has to involve automatons at some point.

Answer (score 3):

Let's use the alphabet {0,1}.

Let *L*<sub>1</sub> be the regular language containing all strings of length 3, {000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111}; we can use the regular expression '(0+1) (0+1) (0+1)'.

Let *L*<sub>2</sub> be the regular language containing all strings starting with 0, {0, 00, 01, 000, 001, 010, 011, …}; we can use the regular expression '0 (0+1)*'.

The union of these languages contains all strings of length 3, plus all strings starting with 0. The + operator does exactly this, so we can just write '(0+1)(0+1)(0+1) + 0(0+1)*'. (We could simplify this expression slightly, but we don't need to.)

The intersection of these languages contains all strings of length 3 that start with 0: '0 (0+1) (0+1)'.

The complement of *L*<sub>1</sub> contains all strings of length 0, 1, 2, or ≥4; we can write 'ε + (0+1) + (0+1)(0+1) + (0+1)(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)*'.

The complement of *L*<sub>2</sub> contains the empty string, plus all strings starting with 1; we can write 'ε + 1 (0+1)*'.

---

**Edited to add:** That said, as some commenters mention above, it's probably easier to picture this using finite state machines. In particular, DFAs (deterministic finite automata) are probably the way to go.

Here are DFAs representing *L*<sub>1</sub> and *L*<sub>2</sub>:

[image: L1]
[image: L2]

We can complete/extend these DFAs, without changing the languages that they define, by adding additional *non*-accept states that we will transition to whenever there is no other state transition. (This way, every string ends up in some state.) That gives:

[image: L1, completed]
[image: L2, completed]

Their union has the cross-product of the states in the two DFAs; for example, it has an "AD" state, meaning "if I were following the DFA for *L*<sub>1</sub>, I'd be in state A, and if I were following the DFA for *L*<sub>2</sub>, I'd be in state D." The accept states are the states corresponding to accept states in *either* DFA:

[image: union of L1 and L2]

Their intersection is similar, except that its accept states are the states corresponding to accept states in *both* DFAs:

[image: intersection of L1 and L2]

Though of course, we can greatly simplify it by removing all the states that can never lead to an accept state:

[image: intersection of L1 and L2, simplified]

The complements, lastly, are simply the same DFAs, but with all accept states changed to non-accept states and vice versa:

[image: complement of L1]
[image: complement of L2]

Comment: You need DFAs for getting the complement, not NFAs, because with NFAs, a given string may lead to multiple possible states, where it's a match if any of those states is an accept state. Simply turning each accept state into a non-accept state and vice versa is not enough to negate that.